# Windows Login Integration

Tags: windows, security, authentication, face-recognition

I am building facial recognition software for a certain purpose, however, as a spin-off i would like to use that same software / concept, to automatically recognize me when i sit in front of the PC, and log me in.

recognition is handled.. however, i need to incorporate this into windows, the same way fingerprint logins work.

where can i go to get some more info on the doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're targeting Vista/Win7, see [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)

For XP and earlier, see [Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) and [Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx)