# How can I customize the login screen for Windows Vista & 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, authentication, user-accounts

I need to create a windows login UI for Windows 7 & Vista which logs user name and image from webcam (replacing their login screen). I don't know where to start from. Can I do this in C# or will I have to use C++? Any link will be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Login Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378549/windows-login-integration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need Windows 7 and Windows Vista support, you are looking for Credential Provider.  You can find some samples in Windows SDK.

If you want to extend pre-Vista Windows, you are looking for [GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

Comment: +1 Dan Griffin's article in MSDN Magazine is an excellent introduction (including sample code!) to customizing the login experience using Credential Providers under Windows Vista: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx