# login screen replacement for windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize the login screen for Windows Vista & 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516578/how-can-i-customize-the-login-screen-for-windows-vista-7)

I am developing a customize windows login screen which will be replaced by default login screen of Windows 7. I need few information for this purpose.

1. Is `C#` right language for this or `C++`
2. If `C#` is good choice then how about WPF for good looking UI.
3. I am able to authenticate user using `PrincipalContext` class, now after authentication i need to display desktop for that user. how i can do that.

If you could provide any **code example** or reference then it would be helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378549/windows-login-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx), you can not use managed code nor can you draw your own UI.

Regarding drawing the UI:

> There has also been an important change regarding which component renders the graphical aspect of the logon. Previously, this was handled by GINA and thus a third-party component could have been doing the rendering. In the new architecture, LogonUI, which is a built-in piece of the operating system, is responsible for this.
>
> So how is per-provider user prompting behavior achieved in the new model? The Credential Provider architecture requires each provider to enumerate its UI elements. For example, in a given scenario, a provider might indicate to LogonUI that it requires two edit boxes, two captions, a checkbox, and a bitmap. In turn, LogonUI renders those controls on behalf of the credential provider. This goes a long way toward achieving the goal discussed previously-a consistent look and approach that supports a broad set of evolving authentication scenarios.

Regarding managed code:

> The credential provider architecture and its host support only native code.